# Convert SQL Server query to Oracle equivalent

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Can someone please help me convert the below SQL Server queries to their Oracle equivalents?

Also, I am not able to understand the functionality of the query.

```
select 
    [sco_nm], count(1) as cnt 
from 
    (select 
         [sco_nm], DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [TIME_CREATED])) as DATE_CREATED
     from 
         [dbo].[sc_sm_res]
     group by 
         [sco_nm], DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [TIME_CREATED]))) as rec   
group by 
    [sco_nm]

   
SELECT 
    CAST(GETDATE() AS datetime2(0)) AS CURR, 
    [SC_SM], [PF_VSR_K], [PF_RN_K]
FROM 
    [dbo].[sc_sm_res]
```

I tried to check some other posts but couldn't understand the functionality.

Comment: I have removed inconsistent tags

Comment: You need to have a go! Otherwise you're just getting us to do your work for you.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, Yes I will, there are bunch of queries I have to work upon but a little lift does help isn't it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, You don't need group by in sub-query or even you don't need sub-query. and you can use `trunc` as follows:

```
select sco_nm, count(distinct trunc(TIME_CREATED)) as cnt 
  from sc_sm_res rec 
 group by sco_nm
```

For second query:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as CURR, 
       SC_SM
      ,PF_VSR_K
      ,PF_RN_K
  FROM sc_sm_res
```

Comment: Don't we need to replace the dateadd and datediff here?
Also, there are two queries for which I need the oracle version.

Comment: `DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [TIME_CREATED]))` in sql server is equal to `trunc(time_created)` in oracle

Comment: Thanks. That's nice to know!!
Also, Can you reply for the second query?

Comment: Updated the answer with second query too

Comment: Thanks Much @Popeye-- This should get me going. I also read and figured out this DADD is just to strip of the time portion from the date.

Comment: I just noticed that the 2nd query has a datatype of datetime2(0) but the solution u have provided has to_char ?

Comment: Yes, because that will display the date in particular format. If you want to use the column as date then in oracle, you can just use direct `sysdate`

Comment: The problem is I have two dates date 1- 2021-01-21 16:51:04.0 (date/time)
date 2-- 2021-01-22 01:37:33 (string)
I am checking for date 2> date 1 and it's not matching